# Probabilistic solution of Dirichlet Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $D\subset\Bbb R^d$ be an open and bounded set, $f:\partial D\to\Bbb R$ continuous.

We say that $F:\overline D\to\Bbb R$ satisfies the Dirichlet problem with boundary condition given by $f$, if
\begin{align*}
&F\in\mathcal C(\overline D)\cap\mathcal C^2(D)\\
&\Delta F\stackrel{D}{=}0\;\; \\
&F\stackrel{\partial D}{=}f\;\;.
\end{align*}

If now we take a $d$-dimensional browninan motion $B$, we set $B_t^x:=x+B_t$ for fixed $x\in\Bbb R^d$ and $\tau:=\inf\{s\ge0\;:\;B_s^x\in D^C\}$, which is a stopping time, a.s. $<+\infty$.

There is a Theorem, which states that if the solution to the Dirichlet Problem exists, then it's unique and $\forall x\in D$ it is given by
$$
F(x)=\Bbb E[f(B_{\tau}^x)]\;\;\;.
$$
My problem is: why is this solution well defined? Doesn't $F$ change if we change the BM inside the mean value?

Comment: What do you mean change the BM? Change the realization? You are averaging over all realizations already.

Comment: @Ian: maybe I'm losing myself in glass of water. We know that e.g. if $X\sim N(0,1)$ then $\Bbb E[X]=0$... and this true for every such r.v. Similiarly, the distribution of the BM is the Wiener measure, thus the mean value doesn't see the choice of the particular BM I'm taking. Thus $\Bbb E[F(B)]$ is well defined, since it doesn't depend on the particular choice of $B$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, $E[F(B)]$ will be the same for any particular BM, because $B$ and hence $F(B)$ have the same distribution for any BM $B$. That required that F is a deterministic function...but it is, so that's no obstacle.

Comment: @Ian: OK! MANY THANKS!!